# Edit SQL Server backup file to change database and file paths to allow restoring multiple times to same Amazon RDS instance as different databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

**Goal**:  Backup and Restore a SQL Server database multiple times onto an Amazon RDS SQL Server instance with different database and file names.

So Amazon RDS added the ability to access SQL Server database backups and "import" and "export", yay! But you can't change the database name or the file names, boo!

For non-production databases, I want to put them on a single RDS instance, e.g. dev, test, integration, etc. since I don't need much performance and it would save a lot of money.

I have been seeking to come up with a solution for cloning a database onto an Amazon RDS instance, specifying the database name. I don't want to (i.e. not allowed to) spend $6000 for Red Gate SQL Clone. Trying to hack a combination of scripting, bcp, import/export, etc is likely going to take a lot of time.

With the introduction of import/export a database in RDS via SQL backups, I have a new option.  The problem is I can't specify database and filenames on "import"(restore).

I thought about writing a script that gets the database backup from RDS, restores it to a local SQL Server Express instance specifying the database name and files that I'll want on the destination, then backup this, then import/restore to Amazon. This is an option but it will take WAY longer than is probably practical.

So...  my final thought at this point and my question: is there a reliable way to simply edit/patch the backup file to change the database and file names?

Comment: `backup to disk..` using sql command, you could rename the file?

Comment: It's not clear that this is possible - the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) say `You can't restore the same backup file to a DB instance multiple times. That is, you can't restore a backup file to a DB instance that already contains the database that you are restoring. Renaming the database is not a workaround for this limitation.` - although I'm not sure I've understood this limitation properly, or how it would be enforced.

Comment: @LONG This is all in the context of Amazon RDS which has many limitations with SQL Server.  I cannot executable BACKUP or RESTORE DATABASE directly.  All I have access to is the ability to EXPORT a database to a backup file via a stored procedure and IMPORT a database.   This is an Amaon RDS limitation.

Comment: @EdHarper - That limitation in Amazon RDS is exactly what I'm attempting to overcome.  From what I can gather, because Amazon RDS doesn't give you options to rename the database or the files, you can't use the same backup file twice on the same server because it would just replace the existing database.  So I'd like to be able to modify the actual backup file so I can change the database and file names directly in the backup file.  And doing that is my specific question.  The rest is background.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could afford SQL CLone, I'm not sure it would function on AWS as I believe it requires Windows Hyper-V, which isn't supported on Windows Server VMs on AWS.

Windocks has also just released support for SQL Server cloning, but they also use Hyper-V based approach . . . so if you have options outside of AWS I believe their solution fits your budget . . . but again, not on AWS.

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*